# To start the Desktop Search in Ubuntu?

Tags: search

I pressed some key bindings to start the desktop search bar in Ubuntu. 
I cannot find it again. 
It was something with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>

How can you start the search box on top of everything in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press Window key (My Macbook Air > CMD). Read the manual > Dash > Super + [A,F,M,C,V] for App, Files, Music, Photo and Video, respectively. If too slow, use system-wide searches in specific settings

- .tex files [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/789769/25388)
- ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> which shows this dialog

[image]

---

If you want to search in nautilus you have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> which shows this dialog:

[image]

Comment: Please give a feedback. Is this what you want?

Comment: This is used when you are in Desktop not from nautilus or other application since those apps have their own shortcuts which override this, to test it minimize all windows on desktop and try it

Comment: check edit ctrl+f. Is this what you want?

Comment: It's ctrl+s as shown above, but check the active window while pressing it