# How to search .tex files?

Tags: search, latex

I want to search *methyldopa* in .tex files by the Ubuntu search. I just included the files in my Dropbox folder which may be confusing Ubuntu's search tool. However, I see those files in Recent files of the search tool. I search also unsuccessfully `methyldopa .tex` but also doing unsuccessfully just `methyldopa` and limiting *Type* to Documents, Folders and Other.

I run `sudo updatedb` and still unsuccessful searches.

How can you search .tex files in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Comment: You don't want command line options, I suppose?

Comment: Looks like it is taking some time for those files to be indexed. Try running `sudo updatedb`

Comment: @Ron `updatedb`? You should read `man updatedb` and `man locate`

Comment: @A.B. looks like someone found that useful. http://askubuntu.com/questions/612354/make-unity-file-lens-find-all-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the script which I call `haetex` for the system-wide search. Put the script to `/usr/local/bin/` as just `haetex` with such permissions/owners; which you can do by `sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/haetex`

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  932 Jun 21 17:16 haetex
```

Characteristics

- use `find -L ... -exec fgrep -l ... 2>/dev/null` because it takes a bigger space in the system than `find -H ... -exec fgrep -l ...`, without giving errors about faulty symlinks
- I think `fgrep` fits here better than `grep`
- `/dev/null` is necessary in the second command set because we are using `find -L`, since we want to include all symlinks and go them through and not exclude anything in the search

File `haetex`

```
#!/bin/bash
# $Id: haetex, v 0.01 2016/5/4 17:33:12 Masi $
# v 0.011 2016/7/1 08:28:11 Masi $ [location], show filename when one file, search symlinks by default 
# v 0.012 2016/8/16 19:21:00 Masi $ fix for find: ‘/home/masi/LOREM’: Too many levels of symbolic links


# Search .tex files
#
# .vimrc
# http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7782/2923
#
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/287344/16920

usage() {
# a function that prints an optional error message and some help.
# and then exits with exit code 1
[ -n "$*" ] && printf "%s\n" "$*" > /dev/stderr

cat <<__EOF__
Usage:
      $0 [-h] [ -i ] [ location ] [ word(s) ] [ -x example_data ]

-i    Ignore case
-x    The example option, requires an argument.
-h    This help message.

Detailed help message here
__EOF__

exit 1
}

case_option=''
case_example=''

while getopts "hix:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        h) usage ;;
        i) case_option='-i' ;;
        x) case_example="$OPTARG" ;;
        *) usage ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

# include symlinks
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293147/16920
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303694/16920
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304027/16920
find -L "$1" -xtype f -name "*.tex" \
   -exec fgrep -l $case_option "$2" {} + 2>/dev/null | vim -R -
# The /dev/null makes sure `fgrep` prints a filename even when it has only a single file to search. 

# TODO +perm 0666 not working in Ubuntu 16.04; instead fix the origin of the permission denied alerts
#sudo gfind /Users/masi/Math/ -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
#sudo gfind /Users/masi/Math/ -iname '*.docx' ! -readable -exec chmod 0644 {} \;

# TODO remove -l but make opening file only filename in Vim

# TODO less -s -M +Gg - Less as frontend with selection possibility? Maybe with GNU Screen
```

Select links in the visual mode. Press `Enter` (=leader) + `g` + `t` on the visual mode. Output: files in the tabs. 
So you redirect the output to Vim. 
Expected `$HOME/.vimrc`

```
"" Mapleader is space now from \ 
let mapleader=" "
"" Quick tabs - Go to tab by number 
noremap <leader>1 1gt
noremap <leader>2 2gt
noremap <leader>3 3gt
noremap <leader>4 4gt
noremap <leader>5 5gt
noremap <leader>6 6gt
noremap <leader>7 7gt
noremap <leader>8 8gt
noremap <leader>9 9gt
noremap <leader>0 :tablast<CR>
"" Go to last active tab 
au TabLeave * let g:lasttab = tabpagenr()
nnoremap <C-Left> :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <C-Right> :tabnext<CR>

"" http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7787/2923 
function! OpenSelectionAsTabs() range
    let tabnr = tabpagenr()
    for line in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
        "" to allow whitespaces in names http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7865/2923
        execute "tabedit " . fnameescape(getline(line))
        execute "tabp"
    endfor
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>gf :'<,'>call OpenSelectionAsTabs()<CR>
vnoremap <leader>gf :call OpenSelectionAsTabs()<CR>
```

Press `Space` + `[1-9]` to browse the tabs in Vim.

Known Limitations: none

Systems: Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 16.04, Debian 8.5, ...
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA

Answer (score 2):

Although you are looking for a GUI solution, I would like to share a command line solution, because I think it is quite handy and easy to use:

### tl;dr:

- Use `grep -w methyldopa *.tex | cut -d":" -f1` if all files are in the same directory.
- Use `find -name "*.tex" -exec grep -H -w methyldopa {} \; | cut -d":" -f1` in a directory, where all files sou want to find are in subdirectories.
- **Edit:** Shortest Way (credits to @A.B.): `grep -rwl methyldopa | grep .tex`

### long version with explanations:

#### First Case:

All files, you want to search are in the same directory.
This is the easiest scenario. You can simply use

```
grep -w methyldopa *.tex | cut -d":" -f1
```

to find all `.tex` files containing `methyldopa`.

**Explanation:**
Directory and file content:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.list

#file1.txt
foo
bar
foobar

#file2.txt
foo
foobar
1337

#file3.list
foo
bar
foobar
```

Now, you can use `grep foo *` to search for `foo` in all files. This is waht you will get:

```
file1.txt:foo
file1.txt:foobar
file2.txt:foo
file2.txt:foobar
file3.list:foo
file3.list:foobar
```

Using the `-w` option, will prevent finding `foobar`:

```
grep -w foo *

file1.txt:foo
file2.txt:foo
file3.list:foo
```

If you want to restrict your search to files with a special ending, you can do the following:

```
grep -w foo *.txt

file1.txt:foo
file2.txt:foo
```

Last, but not least, you can pipe the results to a `cut` command to extract only the filenames (`-d":"` sets the field separator to `:`, `-f1` returns the first field of each line):

```
grep -w foo *.txt | cut -d":" -f1

file1.txt
file2.txt
```

#### Second Case:

Your files are in different directories. In this case, you should use `find` to find the files first:

```
find -name "*.txt" -exec grep -H -w foo {} \; | cut -d":" -f1
```

**Explanation:**

`find -name "*.txt"` searches for files ending with `.txt` in your current directory and all subdirectories. You can use something like `find ~/Documents/ -name "*.txt"` to start searching at `~/Documents`.

`-exec grep -H -w foo {} \;` searches for `foo` in each file that was found and returns something like this (the `-H` flag makes sure, that the filename is printed):

```
./testdir/file2.txt:foo
./testdir/file1.txt:foo
```

Like in the first case, `| cut -d":" -f1` cuts out the filenames from the output.

Comment: The easiest way is a `grep -rwl methyldopa *.tex`

Comment: @A.B. damn - I did not think about that one ;-)

Comment: @A.B. Your command is searching only in one directory. I think you need to expand it with `find` to get search in many directories.

Comment: @Masi No, `-r` is for `recursive`

Comment: @A.B. Unsuccessful in my system for many directories. It only searches the current directory, even with `grep -rwl and *.tex`.

Comment: I just checked this. `grep -rwl foo *.tex` searches recursive through directories which end in `.tex`, because bash expands `*.tex` to all elements matching in the current directory first. So `grep -rwl foo | grep .tex` works

Answer (score 2):

For a graphical solution (and a more powerful one, when it works correctly --- which is most of the time) is to install [`recoll`](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/).

You will need to install it [using the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) --- look at the [download instructions](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/download.html) (scroll down to the part for Ubuntu systems).

After having installed it, choose a kind of indexing (I do mine overnight f[or this still unresolved problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/recoll/+bug/718427) --- which is probably due to some strange configuration in my system), you have a very powerful tool to find files in your system (even contents of files like ODS spreadsheet or compressed archives ort similar things).

In your case simply call the Recoll interface:

[image: recoll interface]

(I used "puente" as the search term because I have no methyldopa around ;-)) --- the search is written in the [recoll query language.](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/RCL.SEARCH.html).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Recoll for an indexed search with a graphical interface and a preview functionality! It is in the official repositories, easy to use and very powerful.

Comment: Recoll seems to be a descent tool with active development. Do you know what are the benefits of having *python-recoll* extension with Recoll?